# Android TCP Client send data

Tags: android, tcpclient

I'm trying to make a simple TCP android client which should connect once to a server, using an async task and then send several messages on a button click.

I managed to make the connection part in this way:

```
class TcpTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>{

    Socket socket;
    PrintWriter outToServer;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        try
        {
            socket = new Socket("192.168.2.168", 1234);

            outToServer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            outToServer.print("Ciao");
            outToServer.flush();




        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!:");
            System.out.print(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        return null;
    }





}
```

but i'm not able to send other messages to the server neither from the onPostexecuted method nore from the MainActivity passing the outToServer PrintWriter.

Is there a way to achieve this or do i have to create a new socket each time i want to send a message?

Comment: No. You can use the same socket and streams. But all internet code has to be in another asynctask or thread.

Comment: Ok, so do i have to pass outToServer PrintWriter to another AsyncTask? How?

Comment: Why are you calling a PrintWriter outToServer? You write unreadable code.

Comment: Make your PrintWriter variable a member of the Activity. Not of the asynctask.